# Survey 123 Webhook for Edits

Tags: arcgis-survey123, microsoft-flow

I use a [webhook from a Survey 123 form](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/survey123/field-mobility/survey123-microsoft-flow/). It sends an email to a staff member when the form is submitted. It does this via Microsoft Flow. Now what I am looking to do is have a separate flow for when edits are made to an existing record in the Survey 123 form.

I haven't been able to find any way to do it without some server scripts. I'd much rather have it be within a flow.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Survey123 WebHooks](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/create-surveys/webhooks.htm) help topic, **existing record edited** is an option to fire a webhook. This should do what you need. However, you may need to setup a custom connector, **When a HTTP request is received**... instead of using a ready made Survey123 connector.

Alternatively, if you're using a Feature Service from ArcGIS Online, these [support webhooks with an edit trigger](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/online/web-hooks-create-feature-service-.htm). However, you'll need to manually setup the integration into Power Automate.